# Mysql get date range, hour, minute and second?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Hello to the community I want to get the query for between the date range as follows:

Considering that the field of the table is a **datetime**

```
2017-04-18 15:00:00 and 2017-04-19 14:59:59
```

Comment: Please improve your questions. This is confusing as all get up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need

```
    SELECT whatever
      FROM table
     WHERE datestamp >= '2017-04-18 15:00:00'
       AND datestamp <  '2017-04-19 15:00:00'
```

Notice the use of `<` for the end of the range. That's more robust than trying to literally express the very last moment of the range.